# MYSQL trim dynamically

Tags: mysql, trim

I have a column value like "123|34|65|35" in MYSQL database how can I remove the last "|35" from the column value through a select query?

example:
this is my table values
+--------------------+
 Values             
+--------------------+
 45|56|2|2015|22    
+--------------------+
 28|40|59|205|7     
+--------------------+
 44|38|29|15|257     
+--------------------+

I want to a select query that should gives me the below output

+--------------------+
 Values             
+--------------------+
 45|56|2|2015        
+--------------------+
 28|40|59|205       
 
+--------------------+
 44|38|29|15        
 
+--------------------+

any ideas ! the last character is a dynamic character.

Comment: i tried like trim the column value based on the trailing "|" but isn't  work for me !!

Comment: It looks like the columns are complex domains, meaning the table isn't in [1st normal form](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/26933/first-normal-form-why-is-it-good-and-how-does-it-reduce-redundancy). You'd do well to read up on DB design and [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '|', 4) FROM table;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7f09b/1)

Replace that number with the nth instance of the | separator in each of those strings.

Comment: that will not give the solution "|35" is not constant its dynamic.

Comment: @user3028959   I`M so very sorry I`m not a psychic.